# How can i execute a fabric task on a host that is not available directly through the internet, through a proxy host?

Tags: python, fabric

I have a frontend server that is reachable over the internet, and a database server that is only available in the local network where the frontend and database server are both in.

I need fabric to create a new database on the database server, but as the database server is not available on the internet, I need to "proxy" through the frontend server to call tasks on the database server.

How can I do that?

Comment: Which options have you considered so far ?

Answer (score 0):

I searched for the answer for a few hours, but of course I only found it after asking about it here on stackoverflow.

The solution is to set the frontend server which is available through the internet as the gateway, either using the `--gateway|-g` flag in the command line, or by setting `env.gateway`.

I use this in combination with the `env.roledefs` property and `fabric.api.roles` to execute some tasks on the database server.

The solution roughly looks like this:

```
from fabric.api import task, env, roles

env.gateway = 'frontend.server'
env.hosts = ['frontend.server']
env.roledefs = {'db': ['database.server']}


@task
@roles('db')
def create_database():
    """ Run on the database server. """
    run(... mysql create database query stuff ...)


@task 
def who_am_i():
    """ Run on the frontend server. """
    run('who am i')
```